# How to create Cython cdef public class from C

Tags: c, cython

I have following test.pyx

```
cdef public class Foo[object Foo, type FooType]:  
   cdef public char* foo(self):  
       r = "Foo"  
       return r
```

cython compiles that code to test.h and test.c and everything looks fine, but I can't figure out how to create *Foo* object from C-code.

Even if I create it using Cython function:

```
cdef public Foo create_Foo():
   return Foo()
```

I can't figure out how to invoke *foo* method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That answer I've got in Cython User Group:

Public should probably be disallowed for methods, since calling the
functions directly would break subclassing. If you need to
invoke the method from C, write a wrapper function for each method
that takes the object as extra argument, and invoke the method. E.g.

```py
cdef char *foo_wrapper(Foo obj):
   return obj.foo()
```

It's inconvenient if you have many methods, so if you have control
over the design of Foo to begin with, don't use methods but use
functions instead.

Answer (score 3):

Specify `create_ foo` as `def` or `cpdef`. `cdef` - ed functions are converted entirely in C Code and will not be exposed to the Python module.

Comment: cpdef will create a def to wrap cdef?